# How to receive HTTP GET requests in Java application?

Tags: java, http, https, get, http-get

I need my Java application to be able to receive HTTP GET requests like this:

```
https://host:443/{myApplication}?param1=...&param2=...&param3=...
```

How to do that? I mean - getting HTTP GET requests in the application and making it possible to request through `https://host:443/{myApplication}?...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you could do this but the simplest is to deploy a servlet as part of a web application. The Java EE application covers just about everything you could want to do regarding web and enterprise application development. The tutorial can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/home.htm), you'll want chapters 6 onwards. Web applications are deployed into contains for which the two most useful for you would be [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) and / or [GlassFish](https://glassfish.java.net/).